# Android : Video not playing in Videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play video inside a videoview but a blank video view is showing. The video view is inside a popup window. The video is stored in the external directory and I am using `setVideoPath` to pass the file path.
java code for it:

```
final View videoPopupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_video_preview, null);

        Button cancelVideo = (Button)videoPopupView.findViewById(R.id.cancelVideo);
        Button confirmVideo = (Button)videoPopupView.findViewById(R.id.confirmVideo);
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)videoPopupView.findViewById(R.id.popupVideoView);

        final PopupWindow video_popup_window = new PopupWindow(videoPopupView,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);

        if(new File(attachment_Path+attachment_Name).exists())
        {
            video_popup_window.showAtLocation(videoPopupView, 1, 0, 0);
            videoView.setVideoPath(attachment_Path+attachment_Name);
            if (mediaController == null) {
                mediaController = new android.widget.MediaController(MainActivity.this);
            }
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        }
```

And the popup layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/popupVideoView"
        android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/cancelVideo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:text="Attach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/confirmVideo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have referred other solutions and tutorials but everywhere its done like this only. Can someone tell me what is it that I am missing?

EDIT:
This is the file path that is going through :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Movies/issue_2016_12_30_15_31_13.mp4
```

EDIT2:
Codec Info:

```
Stream 0
    Type: Video
    Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
    Language: English
    Resolution: 720x1280
    Frame rate: 5.564744
    Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
Stream 1
    Type: Audio
    Codec: AMR narrow band (samr)
    Language: English
    Channels: Mono
    Sample rate: 8000 Hz
    Bits per sample: 32
```

Comment: Is the file path correct

Comment: Yes, to check that, I put the if condition in the code.

Comment: Please check the video format https://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/supported-video-format-for-android.htm

Comment: @sukumar the video's MIME type is mp4. I used MediaMetadataRetriever to check.

Comment: check video format in baseline profile and send device name and model.

Comment: @ashwinx Mostly if pull normal video and try to put it inside emulator can't be play will be show. If you insist your video format is correct please check wether it can be play by emulator system, open up emulator gallery and play that video. Come back after you try it.

Comment: @teckwei I am able to play the video from the gallery of the phone that I am using. I think that is what you mean if I am not wrong.

Comment: @sukumar How to check format in baseline profile?

Comment: check with some video editor.

Comment: check weather base profile or high profile.

Comment: @sukumar I couldn't get the profile info but I added the other codec information.

Comment: Check with some other video and some other device.

Comment: @ashwinx could u try test it with another video?

Comment: @teckwei I tried it on another device with other videos but still  couldn't solve it. I am able to play it on vlc or other media players and from gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for a custom dialog, add this code -

```
Dialog mVideoDialog ;
VideoView mVideoFullScreen;
MediaController controller;
Create a method -

mVideoDialog = new Dialog(this);
    mVideoDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mVideoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    mVideoDialog.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mVideoFullScreen = (VideoView)     mVideoDialog.findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
    controller = new MediaController(this);
    showVideo();
     }
//Show video method to play the video file -

public void showVideo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mVideoDialog.show();
     mVideoFullScreen.setVideoPath("file:///sdcard/video file name.m4v");
     controller.setMediaPlayer(mVideoFullScreen);
     mVideoFullScreen.setMediaController(controller);
     mVideoFullScreen.requestFocus();
     mVideoFullScreen.start();
    }
```

try this code